# Why did I get a wrong IP and certificate for www.facebook.com just now?

Tags: tls, certificates, dns, ip

I just navigated to www.facebook.com and my browser alerted me that an invalid certificate has been received. I checked the cert in question, and I was surprised to see that the Common Name on it was www.hackermagnet.com.

After the initial freaking out, I started up Wireshark, reloaded facebook and checked the packets transmitted. I saw that the response to the DNS query for www.facebook.com was, in fact, the IP of this www.hackermagnet.com.

While I do have a notoriously bad router, I considered it could have cached the wrong address for facebook, but I don't think I've ever visited  hackermagnet for that to happen. Could this be a rare ISP mixup or something like that? Besides, even if I asked hackermagnet for its certificate, why would it respond when in the Server Name Indication extension header I can see that my browser asked for facebook's certificate specifically?

The issue fixed itself after a while but this whole thing worries (and baffles) me.

Thank you for your time.

My computer uses 192.168.2.1 (my router) as a DNS, while the router obtains DNS info automatically via the PPPoE interface. Currently the router's DNS servers are 62.38.1.81 and 62.38.0.81 (secondary).

Comment: I'd look to your DNS settings on your computer, router, etc. All the way up the chain.

Comment: I second @schroeder's comment. Look into your DNS settings. Computer, router, web browser's proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like either your router or your ISP's DNS server was hit by a DNS cache poisoning attack. The following article describes how this might occur: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2277316/tech-primers/how-dns-cache-poisoning-works.html

Because this only is able to change the configuration for the Time To Live (TTL) of the domain being hijacked (facebook.com), it will go away of its own accord once that time has expired, unless the attacker is able to repeat the attack.

You may want to configure the systems on your network as well as your router itself to consult a (more or less) trusted public DNS server in place of those provided by your ISP. One example is [Google Public DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange but it means that domain was translated to IP of `www.hackermagnet.com`. As I checked it is not behind CDN and IP is *stable*: `195.154.223.98`.

Whatever it is resolution of the name might be cached in your web browser. Chromium/Chrome has this - check `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and this [thread](https://superuser.com/q/203674/210769).

I would suspect that somewhere DNS resolution was incorrectly cached/done:

- in web browser - cache issue?
- on your DNS - it might be router if you have default DHCP configuration pointing to your router, not to public DNS assigned by ISP
- on ISP DNS - ugly.. but it might happen

Comment: I can confirm it's not a browser issue, as the same issue existed on a different computer, but it didn't exist on the original computer on a different network.